# Dynamic buttons rendering slow in xamrain forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am adding some dynamic buttons to a Xamarin forms page but the drawing of the buttons is really slow and noticeable on the device and the simulator is their anyway of speeding it up its only six buttons for sessions.

BTW I am viewing in the android simulator which is normally fast for me maybe the drawing routine is just slow on that

```
public async void CheckInButtons()
{
    ObservableCollection<Session> myList = new ObservableCollection<Session>(); //your list here
    var test = DayNumber;
    myList = await api.GetAllSession();

    string name = string.Empty;
    checkinButtons.Children.Clear(); //just in case so you can call this code several times np..
    string teamName = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        var team = await api.GetAllTeams();
        if (team != null)
            teamName = team.FirstOrDefault().Name;
        string sessionTime = item.StartDate.Value.ToShortTimeString();
        var btn = new Button()
        {

            AutomationId = StudentId.ToString(),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            Text = item.Name + "\r\n" + teamName + "\r\n" + sessionTime,

        };
        btn.BindingContext = item; // add this here

        btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked;

        checkinButtons.Children.Add(btn);
    }

}
```

I would like it that it is their presented to the user when the page is shown but its drawing it while it loads as am calling it here maybe not the best place?.

```
public CheckInPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   api = new TheHockeyLabMnHttpApi();
   txtMessage.Text = "Please select the name of the team you belong to ";

   CheckInButtons();
      
}
```

Is their a better place to put this ?  CheckInButtons();

Comment: If you want the page to appear, you might want to call `CheckInButtons` from the `override void OnAppearing() { }`. Because now that method is being called as sync.

Comment: Still a slight delay but thats probally code based but better than what it was

Comment: Probably what is taking most of the time it's the API calls. The `await api.GetAllTeams()` does not depend on the foreach `item`. So maybe you should move it outside the loop

Comment: I done that already expecitng that

Comment: This will depend on your API, but maybe you can just get the first `Name` instead of getting all of them and then doing `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: How do xamrain forms buttons get redender is it thru children .add as well

Comment: When you do `Children.Add(Button)` the button is created in the UI and placed. You could replace that action using something like a `CollectionView` and just setting it's `ItemSource`, but lots of changes will have to be made. And I'm not sure if that is going to make it run faster

Comment: When i look at the xarmain code base its doing basically same thing but theirs is instant to the user?

Comment: Like I said before, i think that what's consuming most of the time it's the API